# Stripe create token works with invalid cvv

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using following code for creating the token on UI:

```
const { token, error } = await this.stripeInstance.createToken(this.cardNumber, {
            name, address_zip, address_country
        });
```

I am able to fill the form with wrong CVV code, but token successfully created, and fails right after backend using it.

Is there any way to validate the card before creating a token?

The response, I am receiving from stripe contains:

```
address_line1_check: null
address_zip_check: "unchecked"
cvc_check: "unchecked"
```

Comment: inside your RADAR you have to activate CVV checking

Comment: This is intended behavior. Stripe doesn't perform any checks until you attempt to save the card to a Customer object, or charge the card directly via the Token.

Comment: So, what is the best way to make sure that card, I am tokenizing is valid?